# Nested CSS Classes with Stylus

Tags: css, angularjs, stylus

I am trying to do some animations with AngularJS and ran into an issue when trying to use Stylus to set the AngularJS animation CSS classes. I need the final CSS to look like this:

```
.test-animation-class.ng-hide-remove,
.test-animation-class.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity 0
}
```

I tried the following Stylus:

```
.test-animation-class
  &.ng-hide-remove
  &.ng-hide-add
    &.ng-hide-add-active
      opacity 0
```

But that comes out looking like this:

```
.test-animation-class.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-add-active,
.test-animation-class.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active {
    opacity 0
}
```

Is there a way to specify the `.ng-hide-add-active` class to be only on the immediate parent CSS class, `.ng-hide-add`, and not the `.ng-hide-remove` class?

Comment: Wow, what a great, well thought-out question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this works?

```
.test-animation-class
  &.ng-hide-remove
  &.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active
    opacity 0
```

Comment: I thought there might be another way to generate it without combining the two classes but it seems there is no way to reference the immediate parent.  https://github.com/LearnBoost/stylus/issues/802

Comment: Yeah, I am currently doing it this way. I was just wondering if there was an immediate parent selector. Thanks for the feature request link.

Answer (score 0):

runTarm's answer seems to be the most "stylus" way, but if you don't want to overthink it, this works as well:

```
.test-animation-class.ng-hide-remove
.test-animation-class.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active
    opacity 0
```